# Locks not obeying keepalive setting

Tags: samba

#### Scenario

All our developers work on a Linux server and use Samba to connect their IDEs (mostly ST2/3 on Mac) to their developer instances.

Every now and then when saving a file it will hang up for 20/30 seconds.  I think this has to do with a large amount of locked files.  When I do a `smbstatus -L` there are hundreds, many days old.

It seems that when opening the share in finder, the finder app will keep all these session alive (until finder is force restarted or computer is turned off).

My attempted solution was to set the `keepalive` to one hour, but it doesn't seem to be obeying that.  In my `smb.conf`

```
[global]
deadtime = 1
keepalive = 60
```

#### Question

Why are smb locked files being saved if they're days old and should be being killed in an hour?

Answer (score -1):

Your keepalive is not an hour. The property is in seconds, so you have only 60 seconds. When you need an hour, use 3600. The default is 300.